# Slimmer OSM maps with less data

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik

I am bringing up a tile server with renderd/Mapnik/postgresql. Everything works fine, the problem is that I have no option to restrict my map to a specific region - I need the whole world to be available. On the other hand, I really do not need all the data that the map has (roads, ski slopes, terrain, etc). The planet OSM file is too large, and it takes days to import it to Postgresql.

Is there an option to prepare or to get from somewhere a slimmer OSM map file that will contain only borders and cities?

Comment: You can filter the planet with osmosis or osmium-tool before importing. However I have to set of parameters ready for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks a bunch!